# Connection timeout while connecting to Teradata from Visual Studio vb.net

Tags: package, nuget, teradata

I am connecting to Teradata from Visual Studio vb.net using a Nuget package, I am able to establish a connnect and retrieve records but intermittently the connection timeout happens. Likewise when I connect to the same Teradata DB from python using the teradatasql library, I have never faced the connection timeout issue.

Is it something how I connect to Teradata from the Nuget package.  There isn't much support available on the internet related to the Nuget teradata package.

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: The .NET provider has both a ConnectionTimeout (default 20 seconds) and a CommandTimeout (default 30 seconds). See the [Developers Guide and Reference](https://teradata-docs.s3.amazonaws.com/doc/connectivity/tdnetdp/17.00/help/webframe.html) linked from the NuGet Gallery page. There is no driver timeout if the connection is returning data or idle. As an aside, you might want to try to figure out why 20 or 30 seconds is not enough. And you don't see this behavior in Python because the teradatasql package does not implement timeouts.

Comment: Hi Fred, we have built a front end application in Microsoft Visual Studio vb.net which connects to Teradata using the NuGet package, when the user clicks on the submit button after filling in all the details, an update/insert action is carried out in teradata which just inserts/updates couple of tables, here we are facing the timeout issue. 7 out of the 10 times it works fine but sometimes it gives the timeout issue.  Is there any way of increasing the connectiontimeout value or completely doing away with it?

Comment: An update or insert would use CommandTimeout property of the Command object. Setting the timeout to 0 would potentially wait forever; or set it to some relatively large value (e.g. 90 or 120 seconds) that users would be prepared to wait, instead of the default 30 seconds. You should be able to do this in your application config file; see the documentation.

Comment: Fred in the code we are setting the timeout as below

Dim olddbReader as TdDataReader
Dim cmd as TdCommand
cmd = New TdCommand(sSqlQry, conn)
cmd.CommandTimeout = 400
MsgBox(cmd.CommandTimeout)
oledbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

even after giving the timeout value as 400 we are getting the timeout error

Comment: we are using the NuGet package id="Teradata.Client.Provider" version="17.0.2"

Comment: Then the next step is probably to work with the DBA team to see why the request (command) is sometimes taking too long. Perhaps there is a lock conflict / block or a workload management throttle delay.